# Extract numeric value out of string and multiply its value using chaining command

Tags: r, dplyr, method-chaining

A little portion of my larger data frame presented below.

```
  V0      V1          V2          V3          V4           V5
3301    2012    404.46 M    -            14.34 M     215.61 M
3336    2011    3.9677 B    685.69 M     76.69 M     -0.699 B
3379    2010    61.154 M    -            26.05 M    334.199 M
3395    2013    2.8834 B    18.531 M      6.02 B      1.939 B
3417    2013    296.64 M    -           -3.231 M    268.535 M
```

("datss" data contain six columns of mix characters, the numeric value that is of interest is in col V2 to V5 only)

I am trying to figure out using R `dplyr` package chaining command as oppose to looping function:

1. to extract the value and do a multiplication to its value according
   to corresponding character found in the string (ie, if M - multiply
   value by 10, if B - multiply value by 10)
2. leave everything else (ie, "-" as it is, and "-" preceding a value denote a negative number)

Still stuck with below code

```
library(dplyr)
tesdt <- tbl_df(datss)
tesdt %>% 
    as.numeric(sub(" M", "", tesdt)) %>%    #this one works
    mutate(tesdt, tesdt[,2:6]*10)           #how to do on multiple col
```

Possible solution using `apply` or `lappy`(if any) is also welcome as I'm learning to do away with loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't have `"-"` by itself as an element in the same column as numeric values, so how about `NA` there?  Here's an `lapply()` method

```
df[-(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) {
    suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub(" (M|B)", "", x)) * 10)
})
```

Or with `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_each(df, funs(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub(" (M|B)", "", .))) * 10), -c(V0, V1))
```

Either one gives

```
    V0   V1       V2      V3     V4      V5
1 3301 2012 4044.600      NA 143.40 2156.10
2 3336 2011   39.677 6856.90 766.90   -6.99
3 3379 2010  611.540      NA 260.50 3341.99
4 3395 2013   28.834  185.31  60.20   19.39
5 3417 2013 2966.400      NA -32.31 2685.35
```

As per your comment, you could write a little function so that you can look for either letter and subsequently multiply by its corresponding value in one go.

```
f <- function(x, regex, mult) {
    suppressWarnings(as.numeric(sub(regex, "", x)) * mult)
} 

df[-(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) {
    ifelse(sub(".* ", "", x) == "M", f(x, " M", 10), f(x, " B", 100))
})

df
#     V0   V1      V2      V3     V4      V5
# 1 3301 2012 4044.60      NA 143.40 2156.10
# 2 3336 2011  396.77 6856.90 766.90  -69.90
# 3 3379 2010  611.54      NA 260.50 3341.99
# 4 3395 2013  288.34  185.31 602.00  193.90
# 5 3417 2013 2966.40      NA -32.31 2685.35
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V0 = c(3301L, 3336L, 3379L, 3395L, 3417L), V1 = c(2012L, 
2011L, 2010L, 2013L, 2013L), V2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("2.8834 B", "296.64 M", "3.9677 B", "404.46 M", 
"61.154 M"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("-", "18.531 M", "685.69 M"), class = "factor"), 
    V4 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("-3.231 M", 
    "14.34 M", "26.05 M", "6.02 B", "76.69 M"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("-0.699 B", 
    "1.939 B", "215.61 M", "268.535 M", "334.199 M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V0", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Gosh, that was simple n one liner command! Thanks for solution @RichardScriven. The NA is okay as I'm not using the data for summation or averages. My one silly mistake in the question is that, (should be: if B - multiply value by 100). I'll figure it out soon.

Comment: @RidzuanNoor I added a little update to show how you can accomplish both in one go.